# How to use "Connection: close" in HTTP request or separate header and body? C

Tags: c, sockets, http, get, request

I want to download a image through socket in C. In my code I have a fuction that return the Content Length of the body-content. How can I receive amount of content_length data after "\r\n\r\n" in a loop and save it to file? I've heard about "Connection: close" how can I use it?

```
// Generate HTTP request
sprintf(send_buf, "%s %s %s%s %s%s", "GET", path, "HTTP/1.1\r\n", 
                                "HOST:", hostname, "\r\n\r\n");

send_len = strlen(send_buf); //length of request to send
bytes_send = send(sockfd, send_buf, send_len, 0);

if (bytes_send <= 0)
{
    perror("nothing sended\n");
    exit(1);
}

printf("Bytes send: %d\n\n", bytes_send);

// receive data


FILE *fd = fopen("img.txt", "wb");

bytes_recv = recv(sockfd, recv_buf, sizeof(recv_buf), 0);

/*char *img = strstr(recv_buf, "\r\n\r\n");
img += 4;*/

int content_length = content(recv_buf);

//how can I recv() data with length content_length in a loop after "\r\n\r\n"?

fwrite(recv_buf, 1, bytes_recv, fd);
```

after writing this if I remove header from img.txt and change the file to img.jpg the image seems to be corrupted because not all of body-content is received.

Comment: `Connection: close` simply means the socket will be closed after the response is sent. That has nothing to do with your issue. If you are receiving a `Content-Length` header, that value is the size of the body, that is how many bytes you need to read with `recv()`, no more no less. I suggest you read the HTTP spec, [RFC 2616](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616), especially [section 4.4 Message Length](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-4.4).

Comment: I know what Content-Length means but I don't know how to implement my programm so that I can receive body content of Content-Length and save it

Comment: you need to read the HTTP response headers until you encounter `\r\n\r\n`, then parse the number from the `Content-Length` header, and then call `recv()` in a loop, reading into a buffer that you then save to file, until you have received the specified number of bytes. Why is that so hard to understand?

Comment: Ok thx, now everything works :)